# Значения из таблицы 1:1 связанной с пользователем

Tags: python, django, django-model

мне надо получить значение из связанной с пользователем, который сейчас на сайте, таблицы и записать в переменную.
views.py

```
    current_user_points = userprofiles.points
    current_user_id = request.user.id
```

То есть в current_user_points записать значение points у текущего посетителя сайта как это проделано с current_user_id
models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    points = models.IntegerField(default=100, verbose_name="Кол-во очков")
    telegramID = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, verbose_name="Телеграм")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так получить значение из связанной OtO модели для текущего юзера

`current_user_points = request.user.userprofile.points`